# Find a whole sentence in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I am using phpmyadmin , I need to change the sentece, but I can't find it
I tried all the versions but the system couldn't find the sentence
What can i do?

[image]

Comment: Start with looking for a very distinctive word in that sentence. Add another word if you get too many results.

Comment: Which sentence and for what reason? This is just a UI to access your MySQL DB.

Comment: "We also recommend to bookmark our mirror sites " this is the sentence, now it has only one site mentioned I need to add other sites as well

Comment: Please post your schema, sample data and the text you are trying to find.

Comment: "We also recommend to bookmark our mirror sites exampl.com" to "We also recommend to bookmark our mirror sites exampl.com1"